# finding timestamp differences from same column but deping upon the events from other column

Tags: sql, hiveql

i have a bikes timeline table where i have a column of date and a column of events ,the events column have values like `bike_deployed`, `bike_assembled`,`journey`, `bike_cleaning` ,for all these events we have a specific time.What i want is difference in time of `bike_deployed-bike_assembled` ,`bike_cleaning-bike_deployed` and differences in bike cleaning events and all these differences in other columns.

I am using hivesql, and this is what the table looks like:

```sql
    timeline                events   
    2018-01-19 08:18:05     BIKE_ASM
    2018-02-25 06:36:52     ride
    2018-02-26 00:00:00     BIKE_DPLY
    2018-02-26 08:34:56     cleaning
    2018-03-02 13:32:00     ride
    2018-03-06 13:38:42     cleaning
```

What i want :

```sql
   timeline                events    dply-asm  ride-dply  cleaning-dply cleans  
    2018-01-19 08:18:05     BIKE_ASM    38       4            0            8
    2018-02-25 06:36:52     ride                
    2018-02-26 00:00:00     BIKE_DPLY
    2018-02-26 08:34:56     cleaning
    2018-03-02 13:32:00     ride
    2018-03-06 13:38:42     cleaning
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one, but notice that it is grouped by bike_id and finds the difference only between last ride and deploy, last cleaning and deploy etc

```
select
    bike_id,
    datediff(
        date(max(case when events = 'BIKE_DPLY' then timeline else null end)),
        date(max(case when events = 'BIKE_ASM' then timeline else null end))) as dply_asm,

    datediff(
        date(max(case when events = 'ride' then timeline else null end)),
        date(max(case when events = 'BIKE_DPLY' then timeline else null end))) as ride_dply,

    datediff(
        date(max(case when events = 'cleaning' then timeline else null end)),
        date(max(case when events = 'BIKE_DPLY' then timeline else null end))) as cleaning_dply,

    sum(case when events = 'cleaning' then 1 else 0 end) as cleans
from
    <table_name>
group by
    bike_id
```